# Función arroja valor errado [vb.net]

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Buenos días...

Tengo la siguiente función en VB.Net, la cual debe retornar la suma de los valores existentes en un campo en específico.

El campo, tiene la siguiente nomenclatura: "PAX 60 18:00 20:00". Es por esto que dentro se realizan cortes para obtener los valores decimales que estan junto a la palabra PAX y obtener su suma general.

**El Error en la función, es que no logro arrojar la suma de total de estos valores.**

```
Private Function zonaPaga(ppu As String, sentido As String, conn As Object) As Integer
    Dim zp_ As New DataTable
    Dim cont As Integer = 0
    Dim suma As Integer = 0
    Dim query_string As String = "SELECT * FROM Evasiones WHERE ppu='" + ppu + "' AND sentido_serv='" + sentido + "'"
    Dim cmm As New OleDbCommand(query_string, conn)
    Dim dr As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmm)

    dr.Fill(zp_)

    While zp_.Rows.Count > cont
        Dim zp_str As String = Convert.ToString(zp_.Rows(cont)("zona_paga"))
        Dim new_str As String = Mid(zp_str, 1, 6)
        If zp_str <> "" And Mid(new_str, 1, 3) = "PAX" Then
            Dim a As Object = Split(new_str, " ")
            If Mid(a(1), 2, 1) = "," Then
                suma += Convert.ToInt32(Mid(a(1), 1, 1))
            Else
                suma += Convert.ToInt32(a(1))
            End If
        End If
        cont += 1
    End While

    Return suma

End Function
```

Comment: Que valores quieres sumar? en tu ejemplo, "PAX 60 18:00 20:00", cual debe ser el resultado correcto? Básicamente es que hablas de valores decimales, cuando en tu cadena de ejmplo no existen valores de ese tipo.

Comment: Por ejemplo PAX 60 18:00 20:00... Debo cortar todo y dejar solo el 60, y esos son los valores que debo sumar.

Comment: Vale si entiendo bien, quieres sumar todos los valores que estén a continuación de PAX separado por espacios en blanco? En tu código, por qué buscas una `,`:`If Mid(a(1), 2, 1) = "," Then`?

Comment: Es porque algunos campos vienen con un PAX 4, 18:00 - 20:00. Esa es la razón por la que debo hacer esa pregunta para poder sumar solo el 4.

Comment: Entonces por favor pon un monton de ejemplos de las cadenas de entrada, un ejemplo de tu salida actual y cual deberia ser la salida, para que podamos entender el codigo y que deberia hacer. A simple vista, anda bien...

Comment: Esos son los dos ejemplos de la cadena de entrada. Y la cadena de salida es solo un entero. 
Por otro lado, estoy haciendo pruebas y al parecer la función anda bien. Pero no estoy del todo seguro, creo que por eso pregunte.

Comment: Había añadido una respuesta, pero tras revisar tu código no veo ningun error en el, debería sumarte los datos correctamente. Con lo cual necesitamos primero saber que error es el que estás detectando, y por otro lado que te asegures de que tus datos de entrada siempre tienen el mismo formato

Comment: Estaba revisando tu respuesta y la verdad, si creo que esta funcionando bien. Ahora si pueden ayudarme a optimizar el código sería de gran ayuda. Ya que tu respuesta me pareció buena desde ese punto de vista.

Comment: Bueno,he recuperado la respuesta por si te sirve para optimizar tu código

Comment: Agradecido de que la hayas recuperado!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En lugar de ir separando la cadena por posiciones, yo te recomiendo usar la función Split que separa una cadena en subcadenas basándose en el caracter o array de caracteres que le indiques. Una vez hecho esto, simplemente reemplaza el carácter `,` por `""`,conviértelo a `Int32` y sumálo. Ejemplo:

```
Dim strings As String() = {"PAX 60 18:00 20:00", "PAX 6, 18:00 20:00"}

Dim suma As Integer = 0
For Each str As String In strings
    suma += Convert.ToInt32(str.Split(" ")(1).Replace(",", ""))
Next
//en suma tenémos 66
```

Tu código (bucle `while` solo) quedaría mas o menos asi:

```
While zp_.Rows.Count > cont
    Dim zp_str As String = Convert.ToString(zp_.Rows(cont)("zona_paga"))
    Dim new_str As String = Mid(zp_str, 1, 6)
    If zp_str <> "" And Mid(new_str, 1, 3) = "PAX" Then
        suma += Convert.ToInt32(new_str.Split(" ")(1).Replace(",", ""))
    End If
    cont += 1
End While
```

Comment: para variar puedo criticar tu solucion? si despues de PAX viene 1500 entonces esto: Mid(zp_str, 1, 6) te corta el numero ;). no se si es un numero valido.. pero pasa...

Comment: Puedes, pero como siempre te equivocas. Esa parte viene del OP, con lo que deduzco que el sabe positivamente que la cadena a analizar como mucho se compone de `PAX ` mas 2 digitos ;)